# What happens when you cast the same spell on the same target twice?

Tags: spells, stacking, anima-beyond-fantasy

I cannot find any rules text that states what happens if you apply two spells to the same target that would then overlap in effect - e.g., let us presume two spells of Weight Increment (Earth 10) are cast, at their base value, upon the same target.  Does the target's weight then increase by 20 kg or by 40 kg?  What if one spell is cast at, say, 80 Zeon (such that the effect of the spell would be to increase the target's weight by 60 kg)?